# python 3.0 "with" syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, with-statement

i have a syntax error with the with statement. i cant figure it out. i am using python 3 and every time i use the with statement it just wont have it. i am trying to make a reader for a txt file and i need this with statement.

```
import csv

value1 = "Spam"

fname = input(open("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: ")

with open(fname, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        if value1 in row:
            print(" ".join(row))
```

i am very new to python its probably very obvious cheers for the help guys

Comment: Aside: if you're opening a csv file in Python 3, you should use `open(fname, 'r', newline='')` instead of `open(fname, 'rb')` (which is how you did it in Python 2.)  See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples).

Answer (score 4):

The syntax error is not caused by `with`, but `print` statement. In Python 3.x, [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function.

```
>>> print 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(1)
1
>>>
```

So the following line:

```
print " ".join(row)
```

should be replaced with:

```
print(" ".join(row))
```

---

In the following sentence, a parenthesis is missing.

```
fname = input(open("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: "))
#                                                                         ^
```

And `open` should be omitted:

```
fname = input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: ")
```

Comment: @user3077551: please edit the entire traceback into your question.  Possibly you have an unclosed parenthesis on an earlier line.